# Casting 1st Derived Class to 2nd Derived Class - Why does it work?

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I simply created two derived class from a base class.
Then created an object of a derived class and converted into base class.
Then from the base class, i converted to derived class number two,
I was hoping it won't work, but it did. 
Can someone please explain me how below code is working... And How do I prevent this from happening...

PS: Now edited the Program to make bit more sense.
Also this is the situation I want to avoid if possible:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal() { std::cout << "I am an animal\r\n";  };
    virtual void makeSound() = 0;
    ~Animal() = default;
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    Cat() { std::cout << "I am a Cat\r\n"; };
    void makeSound() final { std::cout << "Meaow\r\n"; }
    ~Cat() = default;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    Dog() { std::cout << "I am a Dog\r\n"; };
    void makeSound() final { std::cout << "Bark\r\n"; }
    ~Dog() = default;
};

template<typename baseType, typename derivedType>
std::unique_ptr<derivedType> dynamicConvert(std::unique_ptr<baseType> baseObj)
{
    auto tmp = dynamic_cast<derivedType*>(baseObj.get());
    std::unique_ptr<derivedType> derivedPointer;
    if (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        baseObj.release();
        derivedPointer.reset(tmp);
    }
    return derivedPointer;
}

int main()
{
    auto cat = std::make_unique<Cat>();
    auto base = dynamicConvert<Cat, Animal>(std::move(cat));
    base->makeSound();
    auto dog = dynamicConvert<Animal, Dog>(std::move(base));
    dog->makeSound();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
I am an animal
I am a Cat
Meaow
Bark
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Undefined, unspecified, and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, that's part of the contract with `static_cast`. It is resolved at compile time, and thus will not check at runtime that you didn't make a mistake: casting to the wrong type just triggers UB.

Use `dynamic_cast` when you want runtime-checked conversions.

Comment: But this compiles and run giving kinna "expected result"

Comment: This is base class
This is Derived 2 class
Print from Derived class

Comment: @NovoiceProgrammer that the program's behaviour fits your expectations is mere luck (or lack thereof), and does not mean that it is correct. You might experience any result from programs with undefined behaviour, by definition.